# How does one get initiated into Sri Vaishnavism?

Tags: rituals, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava, conversion

How does a non-Sri Vaishnava get initiated into Sri Vaishnavism?  What Sri Vaishnava Acharyas are there in the world today who initiate people?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To be initiated into Sri Vaishnavism you need to do Samashrayanam, AKA Panchasamskaram, a ritual which among other things involves the branding of the shoulders with symbols of Vishnu’s Shankha and Chakra.  [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7jG3GJ8NK0) is a video of the ritual. This ritual can be performed with any Sri Vaishnava Acharya.   Here is a list of Sri Vaishnava Acharyas along with their websites.  Note that some of them are affiliated with Mathams, large organizations, whereas others are Swayamacharya people who only have a small Thirumaligai or sacred house of residence.

Thenkalai:

Mathams:

1. Vanamamalai Matham Jeeyar, affiliated with [Vanamamalai Matham](http://vanamamalai.us/)
2. Chinna Jeeyar Swami, affiliated with [Ubhaya Vedantacharya Peetham](https://chinnajeeyar.guru/chinnajeeyar/)
3. Sri Ranga Narayana Jeeyar, affiliated with Sri Ranga Narayana Jeeyar Matham in Sri Rangam, which was founded by Kuranarayana Jeeyar, son of Ramanujacharya’s cousin Siriya Govinda Perumal
4. Thirukurungudi Jeeyar, affiliated with [Thiru Jeeyar Mutt](http://www.srivaishnavanambi.org/) in Thirukurungudi
5. Tirupati Periya Jeeyar, affiliated with Tirupati Periya Jeeyar Mutt

Thirumaligais:

1. Mudaliandan Swami, who is affiliated with [Mudhaliandan Thirumaligai](http://mudaliandan.com)
2. Doddacharya Swami, who is affiliated with [Periyappangar Thirumaligai](http://www.acharyan.com/)
3. Koil Kandhadai Annan Swami, who is affiliated with [Koil Kandhadai Annan Thirumaligai](http://www.koilkandhadaiannan.com)
4. Dasarathi Swami, affiliated with [Thirumani Thirumaligai](http://web.archive.org/web/20180112004635/http://thirumani.in:80/Thirumani/)
5. Appan Swami, who is affiliated with [Koil Kandhadai Appan Thirumaligai](http://web.archive.org/web/http://www.kkavenkatachariswamy.org/)
6. Bhavanachariar Swami, who is affiliated with Koil Kandhadai Bhavanachariar Thirumaligai
7. Shuddhasattvam Annan Swami, who is affiliated with [Koil Kandhadai Shuddhasattvam Sirupuliyur Annan Thirumaligai](http://www.srissannanswamy.org)
8. Elayavilli Achan Swami, who is affiliated with [Koil Kandhadai Elayavilli Varadhachariar Thirumaligai](http://www.baladhanvi.net/)

Vadakalai:

Mathams:

1. Ahobilam Matham Jeeyar, affiliated with [Ahobilam Matham](http://www.ahobilamutt.org)
2. Parakala Matham Jeeyar, affiliated with [Parakala Matham](http://www.parakalamatham.org)
3. Sri Rangam Andavan, affiliated with a [Sri Rangam Andavan Ashramam](http://andavan.org)
4. Poundarikapuram Andavan, affiliated with [Poundarikapuram Andavan Ashramam](https://sites.google.com/site/munithrayam/)
5. Sri Krishna Desika Jeeyar Swami, affiliated with [Sri Krishna Ashram](http://skcsp.skywalktosafety.org/wp/)

Thirumaligais:

1. Karunakarachariar Swami, who is affiliated with [Nadadur Ammal Thirumaligai](http://nadadoor.org)
2. Navalpakkam Swami, who is affiliated with Navalpakkam Thathachariar Thirumaligai

EDIT: Regarding Thenkalais and Vadakalais, every Jeeyar is either a Thenkalai or a Vadakalai.  So by choosing to receive Samashrayanam from a particular Jeeyar, a person is joining the sub-sect of Sri Vaishnavism that that Jeeyar belongs to.

Comment: I think OP also wanted to know about choosing between Thenakalai and Vadakalai. So, how about including information regarding it? e.g 1.once should follow his parents/kula i.e tradition or if not applied 2.one may choose according to his/her inclination.

Comment: Thank you all on answers and help.. I am highly attracted to adoring Sri Narayana.  So I am looking for a guru to get initiation propriety. Does any of Vadakalai gurus come to Europe ?

Comment: @ArneaHaseljic No, Vadakalai Jeeyars (Acharyas) usually never leave India (although there's one in America).  So you'd have to go to South India to receive initiation from them.  And by the way, Vadakalai Jeeyars have people perform two rituals, Samashrayanam which I described above, and then another ritual called Bharanyasam in which you surrender to Vishnu.

Comment: Does anyone can join to take initiation in Vedakalai  no matter on caste system? pls? I am just an soul who want to surrender to Sri Narayana is it possible for Initiation?

Comment: @ArneaHaseljic Yes, everyone is eligible for Samashrayanam (and Bharanyasam) regardless of caste, gender, etc.

Comment: Keshav Srinivasan thank you on your answer i appreciate it. I would like to take Initiation Samashrayanam and Bharanyasam with all my heart.

Comment: Please help if u can who is guru from Vadakali who come to America and as i search on internet it says Vadakalai are on north side of India..am i wrong? Please if you know any e mail or web of guru from Vedakalai i can contact on english pls any suggestion i appreciate.

Comment: @ArneaHaseljic To be clear, the term "Vada" means northern, but that refers to the emphasis on North Indian scriptures.  But Thenkalai Jeeyars and Vadakalai Jeeyars almost all live in South India.  In any case, the Vadakalai Jeeyar who lives in America is Sri Krishna Desika Jeeyar Swami.  He lives in Pomona, New York.

Comment: when it comes to Mathas i get confused like in one Vadakalai Matha murti is Hayagriva and Lakshmi..my question is if i get initiation by that matha do i have to have the same Murti or i can have Sri Narayana with Lakshmi.. Sorry if i disturb you anyhow. And is it possible to arrange an initiation in India by email because im living in Macedonia .and need to work for a ticket and here there is no one Sri Vaishnava.. please help –

Comment: @Arnea This is not your fault, I advised you to take a tour of the site. But Keshav deleted my comment and you didnt learn how this site works. And he did spoon feeding as well. That is the very problem Because of what instead of editing question you posted an answer. Also I strongly advise you to take the tour of the site. This will help you to learn more.

Comment: Also try to avoid sharing personal info over here. For that we have profile section where we can add our few info.

Comment: Dear LittleNaruto can Keshav Srinivasan and you just really help me with my topic on that profile section or via email or viber im fine with that . You see i really neeed some good info and advices. So please you too can you take some.moments to help me pls.

Comment: Sorry I am not the right person to help you in this topic. I can only help you in pointing out your mistakes made on this site. @Arnea

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, i don't think Krishna ashram is accepted by traditional folks as acharya-peetam (performing samashrayana bharanyasam). Sanyasi and Acharya are different. You can be either without the other.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Would non Brahmin born people with interest in SriVaishnavism be considered for initiation? If yes, please let me know what are the requirements like diet etc.

Comment: @Ajay The answer is yes.  And if you’d like more info, my email address is on my profile page.